# An accelerating rod in special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

If A solid rod is at rest on the x’-axis of an inertial frame $S’$. Then, at $t'_
0 = 0$ the rod starts moving with constant acceleration a parallel to the $y’$-axis, while the frame $S’$starts moving with velocity $v$ on the direction of the $x$-axis (as usual). Calculate the
equation of motion of the solid rod in the $S$ frame. Do you notice anything peculiar? If
so, can you explain this peculiarity?

My question is:
What does the rod look like in $S$ frame? Surely, it is bend, but how? The answer given by my teacher is like this:
[image: Teacher's answer]
However i thought the rod in $S$ should look like this:
[image]
Because the left end of the rod in $S'$ should move first in $S$ frame due to Lorentz transformation. 
Am i right?

Comment: I think that you are right.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that questions of the form "Is this right?" tend to be poor fits for this site because the answer, yes or no, is too short to be a valid answer. Please consider editing the question to be more open-ended and allow for longer answers. Also, be sure to edit the question to [follow our homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lorentz transformation is given by $x' = \gamma (x - tv), \ y' = y, \ t' = \gamma (t - xv/c^2)$

The movement of the rod can (at least in the beginning) be described by
$$
y' = \begin{cases}
\frac12 a (t')^2 & \text{for } t' \geq 0, \\
0 & \text{for } t'<0
\end{cases}
$$
Using the Lorentz transformation we can rewrite it in the $S$ frame:
$$
y = \begin{cases}
\frac12 a \left( \gamma (t - xv/c^2) \right)^2 & \text{for } \gamma (t - xv/c^2) \geq 0, \\
0 & \text{for } \gamma (t - xv/c^2) < 0
\end{cases}
$$
At a given time $t$ the rod follows a half parabola for $x \leq tc^2/v,$ while it hasn't yet moved for $x > tc^2/v.$